# Let go tool pprof collect new data periodically

Tags: go, profiling

I'm using go pprof like this:

```
go tool pprof -no_browser -http=0.0.0.0:8081 http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/profile?seconds=60
```

How can I ask pprof to fetch the profiling data periodically?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a python script that uses `wget` to grab the data every hour, putting the output into a file whose name includes the timestamp.

Each file can be inspected by running

```
go tool pprof pprof_data_YYYY_MM_DD_HH
```

Here's the script:

```py
import subprocess
import time
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    sleepTime = 3601 - (60 * now.minute + now.second + 1e-6 * now.microsecond)
    time.sleep(sleepTime)

    now = datetime.now()
    tag = f"{now.year}-{now.month:02d}-{now.day:02d}_{now.hour:02d}"
    subprocess.run(["wget", "-O", f"pprof_data_{tag}", "-nv", "-o", "/dev/null", "http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/profile?seconds=60"])
```

The `3601` causes `wget` to run about 1 second after the top of the hour to avoid the race condition that `time.Sleep` returns just before the top of the hour.

You could obviously write a similar script in `bash` or your favorite language.